# Race condition in signal handler with static variable

Tags: c, signals, race-condition, signal-handling

In a single threaded program, does a race condition is possible in a signal handler?

```
void signal_handler(...)
{
  static int i = 0;
  i = i + 10 * 10;
}
```

Imagine that two very close signals are thrown, so close that they enter the function at the same time.

I can't find informations about how recent Linux OS handle this. I just know that both signals are correctly handled but I don't know how. Does race conditions are possible ?

Any helps appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no race condition in the sense that you mean (between two signals). Multiple signals of the same signal are not delivered simultaneously. *Unless precautions are taken, multiple signals for different signal numbers may be delivered simultaneously, as described in torek's answer.*

Whenever you involve variables of static duration (or global variables), your function may no longer reentrant. This is typically not important for the signal handler function itself. However, if it calls some other function that accesses global or static data, then that function will see an access pattern that is similar to two threads racing through a critical section. That is, your program is calling such a function to do its normal processing, but the signal arrives in the middle of that function, and then your signal handler calls into that same function. The global/static variables may be in an inconsistent state, and might cause your program to have non-deterministic behavior.

POSIX defines a set of APIs that are safe to be called from within a signal handler. Your code should take similar precautions when you plan to let your signal handler call functions that you implement.

Comment: Thank you too, I supposed it was working this way. Just wanted to be sure ;-)

Comment: This is true if `signal_handler()` is only installed as the handler for *one* signal, but if it's installed as the handler for two different signals then the second signal *can* be delivered while it is handling the first.  See @torek's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Single threaded means only one app touching the static at a time yes?  If there are 2 apps, there are 2 statics and no race condition.

If this is an interrupt handler and i += 100 is not atomic (which it may be depending on the platform/CPU), then it would race.

Answer (score 1):

One additional, important note: if you're using "reliable signals" (POSIX `sigaction` with the corresponding `sa_mask` field), you get control over how signals behave in a single-thread-single-process situation.

Consider the case of single process P1, with a signal-handler like the one you show above.  Suppose that you are catching signal `SIGUSR1` and having that enter the function `signal_handler`.  While you are inside `signal_handler`, some other process P2 sends another `SIGUSR1` to P1 (e.g., via  `kill`).  This signal is "blocked" (temporarily) via `sa_mask` until `signal_handler` returns in P1.  This is true even if you don't set any bits in `sa_mask` (as long as you don't set `SA_NODEFER` in `sa_flags`, see below).

But, suppose you've also decided to catch `SIGUSR2` with function `signal_handler`.  Suppose that P2 also sends a `SIGUSR2`.  In this case, the `SIGUSR2` is (or may be) caught, starting another instance of `signal_handler` running, this time on behalf of the `SIGUSR2` signal.

You can prevent this by making sure that when `SIGUSR1` is being handled, `SIGUSR2` is temporarily blocked as well.  In general you'd probably want to make `SIGUSR1` blocked while `SIGUSR2` is being handled.  To do this, set both corresponding bits in `sa_mask`:

```
struct sigaction sa;

memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa);
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO; /* (decide for yourself which flags) */
sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGUSR1);
sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, SIGUSR2);
sa.sa_sigaction = signal_handler;
error = sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
if (error) ... handle error ...
error = sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sa, NULL);
if (error) ... handle error ...
```

The two `sigaddset` calls make sure that both SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 are held-off (blocked, temporarily) for the duration of the function.

If you're only catching one signal, there is no need for this extra complexity, because as long as `SA_NODEFER` is *not* set, the OS automatically adds whatever signal triggered entry to your signal handler to the "currently blocked signals" set at entry.

(Note that the OS's automatic blocking and unblocking of signals at entry and exit to your signal handler is done with `sigprocmask`, using `SIG_BLOCK` and `SIG_SETMASK`—not `SIG_UNBLOCK`—with the mask for the `SIG_SETMASK` at exit set by saving the previous mask filled in via `SIG_BLOCK`.  Well, it's normally done inside kernel code, rather than actually calling `sigprocmask`, but the effect is the same, just more efficient.)